# Are there any legitimate examples of applications of set theory to Physics?

Tags: set-theory, physics, mathematical-physics

Sets are of course ubiquitous, so in this sense set theory is applicable to physics.

But I'm thinking more like techniques like forcing, or constructs like cardinals or ordinals.

Intuitively it appears unlikely as set theory is directed towards the formal properties of theories aka foundations.

Comment: Physics deals with *this* universe; set theory deals with many *other* universes. With the exception of the axiom of choice being used in quantum mechanics, I'm not sure what sort of examples you might be looking for.

Comment: @Karaglia: How is choice used in QM?

Comment: (If you want the user to be notified, you have to use the first word of their user name; Karagila is also my family name not my given name, which makes this feel strange too.)

Comment: @asaf: the same question directed to asaf :)

Comment: Well, quantum mechanics uses infinitely dimensional Hilbert spaces. And if the axiom of choice fails there can be counterexamples to some things. There's a paper co-authored by Norbert Brunner which deals with peculiar counterexamples to quantum mechanics which may occur if our universe was one of a few particular counterexamples to the axiom of choice. **[LINK TO THE PAPER](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/malq.19960420128)**.

Comment: @AsafKaragila [Here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.0110.pdf) is a paper that discusses non-choice related consequences of set theoretic axioms for QM.

Comment: My first thought was atomic spectra, but that was related to number theory. My second though recursion theory, which makes use of set theoretic arguments when showing that there exist not computable machine functions and that one might relate to quantumn computing.

Comment: @asaf: There are papers by Chris Isham that uses Toposes - which can be considered as generalised set theories - that he uses to discuss the foundations of physics; and Usrs Schrieber uses cohesive toposes to discuss large parts of QFT.

Comment: @Michael: Interesting name appears there. I'll have to question the authors about it some other time. Thanks!

Comment: @Asaf I was inspired to look for it after watching a talk one of the authors gave on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=obMNMoF_CIU), where he disccuses something Martin showed about hidden variables.

Comment: Mozibur, yes but I don't think anyone considers topos theory as set theory per se. If you want to ask about foundational theories interacting with physics that's a broader question. And I'm not sure where on the SE network it might fit (here, MO, Physics.SE, nowhere?)

Comment: @Michael: Oh yeah, I saw part of this lecture. I should watch the rest sometime.

Comment: @Asaf: No, I wasn't suggesting that it was - but was offering it as an example of an answer to the broader question that was motivating this one; as you were asking 'what sort of examples I'm looking for'.

Comment: S. Ulam, *Combinatorial analysis in infinite sets and some physical theories*, SIAM Review 6 (1964), 343-355, might have some of what you're looking for, judging from the title.

Comment: Possibly related question at math overflow: [The Hidden Aspect of Set Theory](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/164326/the-hidden-aspect-of-set-theory)

Comment: There is this book by Zilber: [Model Theory, Non-commutative Geometry & Physics](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/zilber/publ.html)