# Applications of advanced set theory to other areas of math

Tags: soft-question, set-theory

Set theory, from what I understand, aims to provide a solid foundation for mathematics. However, after a certain point, it seems to take on a life of its own. Ideas/objects I would list as illustrations of this are GCH and the existence of strongly inaccessible cardinals. Do these ideas/objects have any consequence for other fields of mathematics? I.e., would the life of a mathematician in any other field be changed if we discovered that, say, strongly inaccessible cardinals do in fact exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to find examples that entangles set theory and fields outside of mathematical logic, but it might not exactly go on.

- Various independence results outside set theory could be examples. This includes [Whitehead problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_problem) and [Naimark's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naimark%27s_problem). See the [relevant Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_statements_independent_of_ZFC) for more examples.
- [Dehornoy order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dehornoy_order) is an example. Huge cardinal influences its discovery.
- It is known that the product of two [CW-complexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CW_complex) is not necessarily a CW-complex. The precise condition when the product of two CW-complexes is again a CW-complex is related to a [cardinal characteristic of the continuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_characteristic_of_the_continuum) (specifically, the bounding number $\mathfrak{b}$.) [See this presentation slide for details](http://www.logic.univie.ac.at/2020/ABTProdsCW.pdf).
- [The rearrangement number](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.07830), which emerges from [a question on Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/214728/48041), is also an example.
- [There is an application of the continuum hypothesis to a theoretical physics.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/822712/53976) (I do not know this result is physically meaningful, but it could have philosophical implications.)

Comment: Neat thread on [continuum and physics](https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2016/09/08/struggles-with-the-continuum-part-1/).